# Segue fail to pass the value to the target VC

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, segue

I am trying to pass a int value from 1st VC to a custom 2nd VC..but with the console, I just find that it fail to pass the value to the 2nd VC...

In 1st VC:

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize numberOfVertexSlider;
@synthesize numerOfVertexLabel;
@synthesize numberOfVertex;

- (IBAction)numberOfVertexSliderChange:(id)sender {
numberOfVertex=numberOfVertexSlider.value;
NSLog(@"value :%i",numberOfVertex);
numerOfVertexLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",numberOfVertex];


-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"polygenPushVertex"]) {
     [segue.destinationViewController setVertex:self.numberOfVertex];
  }
}
```

In the 2nd VC:

```
@interface PolygonViewController ()

@end

@implementation PolygonViewController
@synthesize Vertex=_Vertex;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSLog(@"%i",_Vertex);
PolygonView *pv=[[PolygonView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds Vertex:_Vertex];
[self.view addSubview:pv];
```

can anyone teach me that wht mistake I have made????

Comment: At the beginning of `prepareForSegue:sender:`, add this: `NSLog(@"identifier=%@ destination=%@", segue.identifier, segue.destinationViewController);`.  What's the output?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[segue.destinationViewController setVertex:numberOfVertex];
```